# google docs on firefox: Saving your changes is taking longer than usual. Editing is temporarily disabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

I am attempting to use google docs with firefox, but am constantly getting this message.

[image]

It never goes away.
And if I close the tab all of my work is deleted.

This is a brand new Firefox install.

Is this an attempt to force us back to using chrome with google docs?

I have been a chrome user for many years but was recently forced to switch to firefox because chrome has an [intolerable bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1062493) on macOS catalina.

I need to use google docs but I can't use chrome because of this chrome bug and now I can't use firefox because of this bug with google docs.

Is there a work-around for the problem?
Chrome allows me to work with local copies of google docs without losing work if I lose my network connection, but I cannot find a similar plugin for firefox.

Comment: This should be closed as off-topic - it is not in anyway programming related. If it wasn't bountied I'd vote to close...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue on Firefox, however it seems to work fine at my end without any sort of error or warning popup in saving.

But, Google is known to play nasty with competitors to promote Chrome and it can't be ruled out that it might be a cause too. You can try multiple options, and check which one works.

Possible Solutions:

1. If you want to trick google into thinking you are browsing on Chrome, change this setting in Firefox as mentioned [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/)!
2. Try using the Firefox Developer Edition: [Official Link])(https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/ "Firefox Developer Edition")
3. If the above options don't work, try switching to [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) for a Chrome alternative if the bug is particularly associated with Google Chrome, though they both are based on Chromium, it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Searching through the Google forums, I came across an issue with GDrive not loading in Firefox. https://support.google.com/drive/thread/1987396?hl=en&msgid=22679169

The last comment on the page the user mentions disabling CORS

> Find a solution ! When the add-in CORS (Access-control-Allow-Origin)
>   is enabled impossible to load the google drive page but no problem
>   when it is deactivated.

Have you tried disabling the CORS? http://testingfreak.com/how-to-fix-cross-origin-request-security-cors-error-in-firefox-chrome-and-ie/

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you try to copy/paste info from a place that is restricted. Make sure editing is turned on for all users. If it’s not “shared” correctly it will glitch.